# How do I extract `Abs` and `Arg` values from this expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

Let `s = a + I*b` be a complex number, with `a` and `b` both positive and real. I want to find `Abs` and `Arg` values for this rather gnarly expression:

```
expr = 6^a + 4^(I*b + 1)*((2^(a - I*b)*3^(2*I*b))/
       (6^a*(6^(2*I*b) + 1)^2 - (6^(2*I*b) - 1)^2) - 
       3^(I*b + a)/(2^(I*b)*(2^a*(2^(2*I*b) + 1)^2 -
       (2^(2*I*b) - 1)^2)))
```

But I can't persuade Mathematica to give me either `Abs` or `Arg`. I realise they're both likely to be complicated expressions, but if I try, for example,

```
Abs[ComplexExpand[expr]]
```

I get an expression that is immensely long, but starts with the not-at-all-reassuring letters

> Abs[6^a ...

[image]

I have tried adding assumptions about `a` and `b`, using `Refine`, `ExpToTrig`, everything I can think of.

Can it really be impossible to extract the absolute and argument from this expression? The problem seems to persistevxen with much simpler expressions, so I assume I'm doing something fairly basic completely wrong.

All help gratefully received.

(Mathematica 12.1.1.0 for MacOs.)

Comment: `ComplexExpand@Abs@FullSimplify@expr` works for me and there's no leading `Abs`. It doesn't work with `Arg` though.

Comment: For the `Arg` specify the `TargetFunctions`, i.e., `expr // Arg // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] &`